# How to use "alternative" keys on foreign keyboards?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, input-languages

I apologise for what may be a very basic question.

I am used to an English (UK) keyboard, but I have moved to Romania and would like to learn how to type using the Romanian keyboard, which looks like the below image:

[image: Romanian Keyboard]

How am I meant to use the keys like:

șȘțȚîÎâÂăĂ?

I assumed it would be the alt key, but apparently not. There is also a Romanian (Standard) keyboard which doesn't use what I will call the "alternative" keys, but it's not a particularly natural layout in my opinion.

Comment: Is there a keyboard driver installed for the Romanian keyboard? System Settings --> Language Support --> Keyboard input method system will show it in the dropdown box. Without a specific driver, the keyboard will act same as the UK keyboard. You might also install Romanian (Install/Remove Languages) though this might not add keyboard support

Comment: Also you should always indicate Ubuntu version in your question.